# .NET datetimeoffset to SQL datetimeoffset

Tags: c#, .net, datetimeoffset, sql-server-2014-express

```
sqlString = "Update PortApproach set timestamp48=@msgtimestamp,FLOETA=@floeta where destport=@destport and vesselcode =@vesselcode ";

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@floeta", SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset).Value = floeta.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff zzz");
```

Here is the value string I have tried to update.
 2015-08-21 18:30:00.0000000 +07:00

I got the error "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".

If I update manually in mssql, it is working fine.

May I know how to update .NET datetimeoffset to SQL datetimeoffset

Comment: Hi Backs, I have removed ToString but i did not work.

Comment: what type of floeta is?

Comment: It is DateTimeOffset. That's why I have tried to format as same as value in db. It is working on dev server but it give me error on my laptop and production server.

Answer (score 1):

I am 1 year late to the question but here it is:

```
DateTimeOffset date; //Your date
date.ToString("u", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to install a package for your Laptop and production server. 
Refer Further here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2715289

```
string format = "dddd, MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
floeta.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Comment: Hi Muks, floeta is already DateTimeOffset. I have already tried to assigned  but I got same error. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post Column type of @floeta. 

Is it  datetimeoffset(7)

Comment: Hi Muks, Yes it is. datetimeoffset(7). By the way, It is working on another server but it does not work on my laptop and production server.

Comment: By the way, here is my update sql string. sqlString = "Update PortApproach set timestamp48=@msgtimestamp,FLOETA=@floeta where destport=@destport and vesselcode =@vesselcode ";